# Sending arrays through PHP header redirects

Tags: php, arrays, redirect

Basically I need some help sending array information through redirects in PHP. I have the following code:

Page1: I created the query string and sent it  to page 2, I can get the data in $_GET on page 2.

```
    $qstr = http_build_query(
        array(
            'products_array' => $products,
            'quantity' => $_POST['quantity']
        )
    );

    header('Location: registration.php?' . $qstr);
```

Page 2/3 I get the query string from $_server and concatenate it with the redirect page

```
header('Location: login.php?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

I can send the data using normal href links, but if I try to send it like above I can't retrieve the data past page 2.

If you could give me some input on this problem it would really help.

Thanks.

Edit:
echoing $qtystr gives:

products_array%5B0%5D%5Bitem%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fecx.images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F61Y-rF9tF8L.*SL1100*.jpg&products_array%5B0%5D%5Bbrand%5D=Charmander&products_array%5B0%5D%5Bprice%5D=25&products_array%5B1%5D%5Bitem%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fecx.images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F61vgC3GDI2L.*SL1100*.jpg&products_array%5B1%5D%5Bbrand%5D=Squirtle&products_array%5B1%5D%5Bprice%5D=15&products_array%5B2%5D%5Bitem%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fecx.images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F51TnHKT4oML.*SY300*.jpg&products_array%5B2%5D%5Bbrand%5D=Bulbasaur&products_array%5B2%5D%5Bprice%5D=10&products_array%5B3%5D%5Bitem%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fecx.images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F41MpzoPshAL.*SX300*.jpg&products_array%5B3%5D%5Bbrand%5D=Chikorita&products_array%5B3%5D%5Bprice%5D=20&products_array%5B4%5D%5Bitem%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fecx.images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F51BIJR%252BIqDL.*SX355*.jpg&products_array%5B4%5D%5Bbrand%5D=Mudkip&products_array%5B4%5D%5Bprice%5D=20&quantity%5B0%5D=0&quantity%5B1%5D=0&quantity%5B2%5D=0&quantity%5B3%5D=03&quantity%5B4%5D=0

which is a stupid amount of information to pass in a string (just testing stuff out), sorry, but it's all the information from the two arrays I needed.

Edit2:

I managed to fix it, I didn't give you guys enough info sorry. The problem was actually that I did not set the form action of my pages to preserve the data string, so it kept getting lost as I was processing the form. Thanks for all the advice, I'll be sure to try it out next time, especially sessions.

Comment: You can store the information in a session, it works a little cleaner than passing it in the url..

Comment: please check by echo $qstr in the page itself before using header.I think there is some problem in generating array

Comment: I would pass the information using url_encoded json string I think It would be simpler to Encode and Decode using PHP or JavaScript

Comment: Even considering passing big (>512 bytes) amount of data via headers is a BAD idea, use session or database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only PHP
To encode the data

```
$products = "some product";
$qtd = 1;
$array = array('products_array' => $products, 'quantity' => $qtd);
$json_str = json_encode($array);
echo $json_str;
header('Location: registration.php?' . $qstr);
```

To decode the data

```
$data = json_decode($post_data); //to decode the string into an object
echo $data->products_array . "\r\n";
echo $data->quantity . "\r\n";
```